# How is the C5 SQL base structured?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, microsoft-dynamics, c5

I am working on a PHP/MySQL based ecommerce engine, and need it to be able to deliver orders to a SQL-driven Microsoft Dynamics C5 system.

My plan was to make my mysql structure much alike with the C5 structure, so communications between these two would go af fluently as possible.

However, I haven't had any luck finding the C5 SQL structure with table and field names anywhere. I have tried to install it myself to "leech" out the structure, but with no luck.

Does anyone know where i can find a structure overview or just field list with names and types? Or maybe even a no-data structure only SQL backup?

It would be solidly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly has data structure... an extremely relevant table seems to be `XAL` - AFAIK it is used to generate unique key... it also uses `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` to generate consecutive keys... since C5 specifically is a product of "MS Denmark" I would suspect that you will find most information at http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/c5/threads .

You can install C5 (instead of "Native DB") into a MS SQL Server DB (see http://support.itservicepartner.dk/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=JA_ZzXeag_I%3d&tabid=96&mid=486) - then you can see the structure and access its internal data...

It seems that C5 is going to be updated very soon - see http://www.jdpartner.dk/media/9976/kernel_newsletter_%20c5_4.4.0.186.pdf

I would strongly recommend NOT to go the SQL route to access/manipulate data in C5 DB for several reasons:

- the structure of C5 can change with any update thus making it a "moving target"
- you don't want to read and/or write directly into the C5 database via SQL - this would introduce major dependencies etc.
- define interfaces/structure how and what data needs to be passed from and to your app
  both sides are responsible to implement the agreed upon interfaces independently thus isolating both apps from any internal changes that may or may not happen in the other app
- For C5 there is a WebService interface (see http://support.itservicepartner.dk/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=OjXu5vj0ACg%3d&tabid=96&mid=486) and something called COMAPI (see http://jdpartner.dk/media/6934/comapi%20reference%20manual.pdf) available which seem to be a good starting point for what you want.

I am not sure this really answers your question but hope that at least some parts are helpful.